# WRT54G v1.1 dead - tftp update won't install

Tags: router, dd-wrt, openwrt, wrt54g

I have a rather old WRT54G v1.1 (yes, a G, not GL, not GS) lying around that I intended to use for a small project. Of course I could by a new unit, but I'd prefer to use this old thing and not let it go to waste.

So, for some reason I can't access it anymore. I remember I was playing around with it last time about 2 years ago and did something. Just don't remember what.

Not accessing means:
WiFi and LAN come up and I can connect (also to WiFi), but
-It seems like it doesn't assign itself an IP address, so I can't even ping it. Tried wireshark, but it doesn't seem to have an IP address.
-DHCP also not turned on
-I can send an image with TFTP, transfer succeeds, but then it seems to just continue normal boot, WiFi comes on (with old password), no IP and that's it.

Pressing the reset button doesn't do anything. Neither does the 30/30/30 recovery method.

When booting, supposedly the DMZ light should come on. Which it doesn't. Power LED flashes, but becomes static on after about 20 seconds. WiFi LED becomes static on or flickering after about 20 seconds as well. LAN/WAN become on if I plug a cable.

As I said, I can ping and send an image during boot within the TFTP time window. But flashing the image doesn't seem to have any effect. I don't remember what firmware I used last time. I was playing with OpenWRT, DD-WRT, and Tomato.

What could I do to troubleshoot? Since the device is old, many information has went missing from the web. Not only that, but even back then most people started rather from a v2 unit, and don't know about differences to v1.1. Maybe someone here remembers? Or has any ideas in general? JTAG? Serial?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: OpenWRT has a pretty comprehensive page on the whole WRT54G line: https://openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt54g

Comment: Yes. I had read that, but it's often not very specific to the different versions. However, the issue I couldn't see anything with wireshark was the Windows firewall. I disabled it and found the old IP I had it configured to. Now I am back in. Still surprised as to why flashing from TFTP didn't work.

Comment: We're you trying to use a webflash image? There are tftp recovery images for these routers, it's usually a std or micro to get it up and running, then flash with the web image.